# WSO2 and Java Client periodic requests

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

I generated A Java Client for a WebService deployed on WSO2ESB, through this Client, I tried to send a periodic requests using a loop and Sleep, But I received the same response (Value, time of receiving the request by the WS, time of sending the Response) !!

I have the Stub Class, and My Java Client that I invoke in the Main Class is :

```
package org.wso2.cs.helloservices;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.wso2.cs.helloservices.HelloProviderStub.SayHello;
import org.wso2.cs.helloservices.HelloProviderStub.SayHelloResponse;

public class Consumer {

public ArrayList <SayHelloResponse> consumer(int requestsNumber, int sleep, int reliability) throws 

RemoteException, InterruptedException{
    ArrayList <SayHelloResponse> listResp = new ArrayList<SayHelloResponse>();

    HelloProviderStub Stub= new HelloProviderStub();

    for (int i=0; i<requestsNumber; i++){
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        SayHello request=new SayHello();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");

        request.setSleep(sleep);
        request.setReliability(reliability);
        SayHelloResponse resp=Stub.sayHello(request);
        listResp.add(resp);
    }
    return listResp;
  }
 }
```

The response for example is:

```
Result of Request: 1
---------------------
Receiving Request : 2013:01:24:21:22:30:00935
Sending Response  : 2013:01:24:21:22:31:00935
Response          : Test

Result of Request: 2
---------------------
Receiving Request : 2013:01:24:21:22:30:00935
Sending Response  : 2013:01:24:21:22:31:00935
Response          : Test
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

May be the responses are generated with the cache as they look same. If this is allowed to work properly the service is open for a DoS(Denial of Service) attack.